# replace an object inside an array with reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to replace an object inside an array of object using id to find it,
the payload has the new object

```
const initialState = {
  allComments: []
};

case LIKE_COMMENT:
      let index = state.allComments.findIndex(
        value => value._id === payload._id
      );
      if (index === -1) {
        return {
          ...state,
          allComments: [...state.allComments, ...payload]
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          allComments: [
            (state.allComments[index] = payload),
            ...state.allComments
          ]
        };
      }
```

them problem that it keep pushing that object without replacing the previous one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 case LIKE_COMMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        allComments: state.allComments.map(comment => {
          if (comment.id === payload._id) return payload;
          return comment;
        })
      }
```

this will replace comment with payload and return all other comments

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually need to define a new array based on your old one before returning it into your state:

```js
... else {
  newComments = state.allComments
  newComments[index] = payload
  return {
    ...state,
    newComments
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map to create a shallow copy of the allComments array where the matching index is replaced by the payload:

```
case LIKE_COMMENT:
    return {
      ...state,
      allComments: state.allComments.map(c => c._id === payload._id ? payload : c)
    };
```

Comment: thank you i get it , i thought if i did replace that index i can use it right away .

Comment: `allComments: [ (state.allComments[index] = payload), ...state.allComments ]` replaces the object at the specified index but it also **adds** the payload object as the first item of the array. It is interpreted as `[ payload, ...allComments ]`